# How to display SVG as images with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, svg, rails-activestorage

I'm currently having issues with moving my project from Paperclip to ActiveStorage. More precisely I'm having issues with ActiveStorage and storing svg images.

I know that svg files are images, but they are not variable images. Because of that Active storage for some reason is creating download links and that is why svg files are not shown in browser.

Active storage is neglecting content_type for example (from my seeds):

```
job = Job.create(career.except(:icon, :og_image))
job.icon.attach(io: career[:icon], filename: 
File.basename(career[:icon].path), content_type: 'image/svg+xml' )
job.og_image.attach(io: career[:og_image], filename: 
File.basename(career[:og_image].path), content_type: 'image/png' )
```

Active storage falls to 'application/octet-stream' although 'iamge/svg+xml' is valid image type. I have removed all validations from my models and I have miniMagick gem added to my gemfile. With png and jpg files it is working perfectly.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? And does ActiveStorage even have support for svg files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this code to your config/application.rb:

```
# Hack for allowing SVG files. While this hack is here, we should **not**
# allow arbitrary SVG uploads. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34665

ActiveStorage::Engine.config
.active_storage
.content_types_to_serve_as_binary
.delete('image/svg+xml')
```

You can delete comments of course :). Hope it helps.

Comment: Less hacky way would be to use regular environment config (e.g., in `config/application.rb` or one of the specific environment configs) like this: `config.active_storage.content_types_to_serve_as_binary -= ['image/svg+xml’]`. `ActiveStorage::Engine` is a private API so using config might be more futuru-proof.

Comment: I think that should also work. Is it working because I am not on a project that I was working on so I can not check if it is working.

Comment: We have it in production with Rails 5.2.3. We had the same issue, we used your answer as hint, but we didn’t like relying on private API. Looking around Active Storage implementation for a moment, we noticed additional configuration options like the one above, so we tried those and it works…

Answer (score 4):

Svg are considered binary content types, so that is why Active storage svg links are represented as download attachment links. You can see all content_types and limitations at this link https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/engine.rb.

More about this limitation and explanation can be found here: http://github.com/jdelStrother/rails/commit/06ab7b27ea1c1ab357085439abacdb464f6742bf. I'll post an issue for this. Maybe they will fix it in the future